Blazor 8 SSR - get Entra ID claims with ASP.NET Core Microsoft account
I am new to Blazor on .NET 8, and I searched already a lot, but didn't find the correct answer.
I use the default Blazor .NET 8 SSR template with the AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount to authenticate through Entra ID.
This is all working fine. I created an Enterprise App in Entra and configured it in my program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
})
    .AddMicrosoftAccount(msOptions =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Microsoft").Bind(msOptions);
    })
    .AddIdentityCookies();

but now I try to get given_name and family_name from Entra for the logged in user.
Best would be, if during login the recent claims are read from Entra and written to the database.
Can anyone give me a hint how to achieve this?
All sources I found are for older .NET version (7 or older) but did not work with Blazor / .NET 8 SSR.
Some videos focused on OpenID Connect or Microsoft MSAL but I would like to solve this with MicrosoftAccount (if possible)
